# URLlib2 causing program to stop after 20 attempts

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

so i am trying to write a program wich needs to check for an urllib2 111 error
I do this by using:

```
def Refresher:
    req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/myfile.txt')            
    try:
    urlopen = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 404 or e.code == 111:
                error = True
```

At the end of refresher I update it using because refresher also edits a tk window:

```
root.after(75, Refresher)
```

My problem is that when I reboot the server (and therefor cause a 111 error) this works fine for the first 20 times. But after the 20th time through my function appears to stop running with no error being thrown in the console.Then when the server comes back up my function starts running again.
How do I keep my program refreshing as the function does other things aswell as checking if the server is down?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try printing out all errors (in comparison to only 404 or 111) so we can get a better understanding of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib2`, it's safer to use and easier to understand, if the error persists, then the problem will be in another part of the server configuration.